# Confused with selecting data from db in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, reserved-words

I have 2 tables: `PLAYER` and `GROUP`.

When I call:

```
SELECT * FROM PLAYER
```

Everything is OK but when I call:

```
SELECT * FROM GROUP
```

There is error:

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'GROUP' at line 1`

I don't understand why there is such error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GROUP` is a [**reserved keyword**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) . You have to escape it, like so

```
  SELECT * FROM `GROUP`
```

**Things to note:**

- It is highly recommended not to name the table `group`, it is better to use the plural `Groups`.
- Also, try to avoid `*`.

Comment: +1 :  and then change the table name so it isn't a reserved word.

Comment: and can you advise me new name of table ? I have table where is group of player so I call it GROUP

Comment: @hudi - `Groups` or `PlayersGroups` will be fine.

Answer (score 5):

`GROUP` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and it must be escaped with back ticks.

```
SELECT * FROM `GROUP`
```

It's also better practice to avoid using table names or columns that are reserved words. Also,  specify a column list and not use `*`.

Comment: oh really I forgot thx a lot

Answer (score 3):

Just as you use the reserved keywords SELECT and FROM for constructing your query, there are other reserved keywords like the ones in the following list that you may want to avoid when naming all your tables, views, constraints and columns.

List of (some) reserved keywords: WHERE, ORDER, GROUP, UPDATE, DELETE, CHECK, CHANGE, LIKE etc...

> Therefore, in your case the DB Engine is complaining because a query
>   needs 1 mandatory clause SELECT and optional clauses FROM, WHERE,
>   ORDER BY, GROUP BY, HAVING, LIMIT etc... [read more here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

We might be tempted to use these keywords; especially if they've been modeled in our problem domain (or in the diagrams). For example, a client placing an order yields 2 Entities CLIENT and ORDER etc. or a mechanic performing a check giving MECHANIC and CHECK. or even a FACEBOOK_USER expressing a LIKE.  or in your case there might be a GROUP of PEOPLE for example.

As a general rule, you can transform your entities like so to avoid problems:-

a) The Entity is always modeled (on paper) as singular as it represents a concept/asset/person in the real world or problem domain. eg. ORDER, LIKE, CHECK, STUDENT, CAR

b) the corresponding DB Table it is transformed into is always named using plural.  The logic is that the table will contain lots of instances of that Entity. Therefore ORDERS, LIKES, CHECKS, STUDENTS, CARS

> In the end, you decide because you really can use GROUP if you really
>   want or need to make your table name like a reserved word. Just
>   remember to give them a special treatment by putting them in quotes
>   using the backtick (“`”) when querying.  At the moment of creation the DB engine
>   won't complain, trusting that you know what you're doing.